# I need to retrieve data from database into a Gridview. displaying values must be selected according to dates selected

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridview, webforms

```
   <div style=" margin-left: 214px;margin-top: -42px;margin-bottom:10px;">
    From Date
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtfromdate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtfromdate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True"
        TargetControlID="txtfromdate" Format="dd/MM/yyyy">
    </asp:CalendarExtender>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; To Date
    <asp:TextBox ID="txttodate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="txttodate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True"
        TargetControlID="txttodate" Format="dd/MM/yyyy">
    </asp:CalendarExtender>
           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Select Method
    <asp:DropDownList ID="drpselectorder" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="138px">
        <asp:ListItem>Reciept</asp:ListItem>

        <asp:ListItem>Payment</asp:ListItem>

    </asp:DropDownList>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <asp:Button ID="Show" runat="server" Text="ShowData" OnClick="Show_Click" />
</div>
</p>
<p>
    <asp:GridView ID="gvReport" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvReport_SelectedIndexChanged" DataKeyNames="DbId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DbId" HeaderText="DbId" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DbId" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AccName" HeaderText="AccName" SortExpression="AccName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" SortExpression="Amount" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RecPay" HeaderText="RecPay" SortExpression="RecPay" />
        </Columns>
```

i need to retrieve the data according to the value selected in the select      method and also according the from date and to date selected

Comment: Where is your Select command?

Comment: it isn't a command. it is the drop down list . If i select Reciept in the dropdown list then only Reciept values are to be displayed and likewise with Payment. Also the dates selected must be also considered @AmitMishra

Comment: I'm asking about your select query for bind grid view.

Comment: SqlDataSource1.SelectComand="Your Select Query"